# How to troubleshoot Windows 8 system update failure?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-update, automatic-update

I have seen various system auto update failures such as below. But I got no idea how to troubleshoot it. The `Get help with this error` button is totally useless.

Anyone could shed some light?

[image]

### ADD

I didn't use any security software except the Windows Defender and the built-in firewall.
According to [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/windows-update-error-80072ee2#1TC=windows-7), it could be caused by the firewall, so I disable all the firewall. But the error remains.

Comment: Verify you have followed the advice of the following [article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-update-error-80072ee2#1TC=windows-7) disabling the firewall is enough you need to add the exceptions.  After you add those exceptions you will need to run both SFC and DISM to verify your installation isn't corrupt.

Comment: Have you done any WU troubleshooting yet? I.e. as layed out in [this MS help article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/troubleshoot-problems-installing-updates#1TC=windows-8)? Specifically, have you stopped the WU service, deleted SoftwreDistribution and restarted the server yet?

Comment: the error code 0x80072EE2 means ERROR_INTERNET_TIMEOUT

Comment: I don't know why this question is down voted. I think my answer could help some people with similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By checking the `C:\Windows\WindowsUpdate.log` file, I found that the WU service kept contacting an `SomeCorpNetServer` because my registry has the following value:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate]
"WUServer"="http://SomeCorpNetServer"
"WUStatusServer"="http://SomeCorpNetServer"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU]
"UseWUServer"=dword:00000001
```

Since my laptop is not within the corpnet now, I changed the `UseWUServer` to `0`, and then restarted the WU service and BITS service. Now my laptop contacts the Microsoft public update server and works fine now.

### ADD 1

Today I power on my laptop and launch the Windows Update. And I encounter the update failure again. I check the `WindowsUpdate.log`, it seems the WU service contacts the `SomeCorpNetServer` again.

So I check the registry, and find that `UseWUServer` is set to `1` again. I don't know what causes this (maybe I am sleepy last night and did this unconciously). Or maybe because my laptop is installed with a corpnet OS image and some group policy is in effect.

Anyway, I reset the `UseWUServer` to 0, and everything is fine.

Just remember to check the registry entry.

And the article below is of some help.

http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/windows-xp/Registry-Keys-Tweaking-Windows-Update-Part1.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you EVER used Norton or McAfee products on that machine?
Try resetting the winsocks....
In an Elevated Command Prompt window, run the command

NETSH WINSOCK RESET

reboot on request, and test Windows Updates

Comment: Please see my update to question. I will try your approach. Thanks.